# SQL Query - determine which logical operator is true

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a SQL Query, checking if one of a number of given values already exists in a table, using a bunch of OR x = y statements. I then do a row count on the result.

```
$exists = db_query("SELECT * FROM {leads_client} WHERE (companyName = '".$form_state['values']['company_name']."' 
                        OR billingEmail = '".$form_state['values']['billing_email']."' 
                        OR leadEmail = '".$form_state['values']['lead_email']."'
                        OR contactEmail = '".$form_state['values']['contact_email']."'
                        OR url = '".$form_state['values']['company_url']."') AND NOT 
                        clientId = '".$clientId."'");

    if($exists->rowCount() > 0){
          //Do something
    }
```

What is the cleanest way to determine which of the OR statements was true, without breaking this into multiple queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do raw comparisons in the select:

```
SELECT *, 
    companyName = '".$form_state['values']['company_name']."' AS companyNameMatch,
    billingEmail = '".$form_state['values']['billing_email']."' AS billingEmailMatch,
    ...
FROM {leads_client} 
WHERE (companyName = '".$form_state['values']['company_name']."' 
       OR billingEmail = '".$form_state['values']['billing_email']."' 
       OR leadEmail = '".$form_state['values']['lead_email']."'
       OR contactEmail = '".$form_state['values']['contact_email']."'
       OR url = '".$form_state['values']['company_url']."') AND NOT clientId = '".$clientId."'");
```

This will return a resultset like:

```
|------------------|-------------------|
| companyNameMatch | billingEmailMatch |
|------------------|-------------------|
| 0                | 1                 |
|------------------|-------------------|
```

This way, you'll know which match by the columns with 1's.

Answer (score 1):

Your web site is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  You need to **immediately** read this article and fix **all** of your database queries to use parameters correctly.

Drupal Writing Secure Code:
https://drupal.org/writing-secure-code

Drupal Database Access:
https://drupal.org/node/101496

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `CASE` statement to track which condition was met, something like:

```
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN companyName = '".$form_state['values']['company_name']."' THEN 'condition1'
            WHEN billingEmail = '".$form_state['values']['billing_email']."' THEN 'condition2'
            ...
       END
FROM {leads_client} 
WHERE (companyName = '".$form_state['values']['company_name']."' 
       OR billingEmail = '".$form_state['values']['billing_email']."' 
       OR leadEmail = '".$form_state['values']['lead_email']."'
       OR contactEmail = '".$form_state['values']['contact_email']."'
       OR url = '".$form_state['values']['company_url']."') AND NOT 
                        clientId = '".$clientId."'");
```